# How to convert multiple web sites hosted on IIS to Azure web sites

Tags: azure

I currently have a VPS with another provider. On that VPS, I have IIS running with multiple app pools and web sites. I would like to get out of the "server management business", so it would seem that Azure Web Sites (Reserved) would be a great fit. I'm able to get the Azure Web Sites set up, including the custom domain piece. The problem that I can't seem to figure out is how to get the same URLs and behavior that I currently have on my VPS.

For example, I have URLs that look like this right now:

- www.foo.com/bar
- www.foo.com/baz
- wildcard.foo.com/bla

I can't find a way to mimic that in Azure.

Things I've thought of/tried:

- Go with one Azure Web Site and have separate virtual directories/app pools in Azure, but googling tells me that isn't supported.
- Create 3 Azure Web Sites, one for each of the above. The problem there as I see it is I would need to change to use bar.foo.com, baz.foo.com, and bla.foo.com/wildcard (i.e. lose wildcard subdomain mapping and rework things to have a custom route at the end).
- Maybe have one Azure Web Site with a rewrite URL? The problem I think I'd run into there is that it all runs in one app pool, so deploying one piece will affect all 3, and obviously a fault in one app would impact the other 2.

Has anyone else gone down this path and solved it? If the answer is spin up a virtual server, I'll probably just stay where I'm at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering www.foo.com/bar, www.foo.com/baz and wildcard.foo.com/bla are 3 independent web applications that share a domain (foo.com):

1. Create a Windows Azure Website for each web application. You don't necessarily need to assign custom domain names to them.
2. Create another, separate website and assign to it the *.foo.com domain using an A record. Refer to [Configuring a custom domain name for a Windows Azure web site](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/) for instructions. As documented, "With an A record, you map a domain (e.g., contoso.com or www.contoso.com) or a wildcard domain (e.g., *.contoso.com) to the single public IP address of a deployment within a Windows Azure web site. The main benefit of this approach over using CNAMEs is that you can map root domains (e.g., contoso.com) and wildcard domains (e.g., *.contoso.com), in addition to subdomains (e.g., www.contoso.com)."
3. In this "master" website, set up URL redirection (possibly with status code 307 Temporary Redirect) so that requests go to the appropriate applications.
4. Alternatively, to avoid the delay of the additional request caused by the redirection, set up the "master" website as a reverse proxy that transparently forwards the request to the "inner" web application and sends the response back to the user.
5. As yet another alternative, use a custom DNS service to do the routing at the DNS layer.

This way, each web application is independent and you solve the issue of routing requests to the appropriate application.

Comment: Very nice answer. I need to play with some of these ideas to see how things like session will hold up, and how I would go about implementing 4 or 5. Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate on point 4, the reverse proxy? I am facing a similar scenario: I would like to have foo.com/bar redirect to bar.foo.com. This would be possible with Shared (or Standard) Azure Web Site and I would like to understand if reverse proxy could let me stay with foo.com/bar serving content from (Free) bar.azurewebsites.net.

Comment: I gave you the answer because it was the direct answer to the direct question. However, now that Azure supports Virtual Applications and Directories for Web Sites, I don't need to even go down this path anymore. I appreciate your time and help with the original answer!